# How can I make a graph using matplotlib with specific values. PYTHON

Tags: graph

So, I have a file.txt, and I had to display the temperature, I did that, now the question is

Comment: What type of chart do you want? Bar chart? line chart? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have to do it with a bar chart, but I don't know how to

Comment: Have you looked into the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html)? I recommend going through them, they are quite extensive and provide many examples. I have provided a minimal example below

Comment: Did the minimal examples below helped solve your issues with visualizing the time series? If not, what remaining issues are you facing? If yes, please consider marking them as such

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of chart you want (bar, line,..) and the axis information you want to add (extraction of the "data" information seems relevant). In most simple form, this should provide a bar chart visualisation when `temp`-values are stored in a list:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def temperature():
    with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
        temps = []
        for line in f:
            if "Temperature" not in line: continue
            temp = line.split(" ")[1]
            temps.append(temp)
    return temps

temps = temperature()
plt.bar(x=np.arange(len(temps)), height=temps)
plt.show()
```

See the matplotlib docs for more information: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your code would be return a list, or an array of temperatures and the use it to plot against an x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #importing matplotlib
def temperature():
   temps = []
   with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
       for line in f:
           if "Temperature" not in line: continue
           temp = line.split(" ")[1]
           temps += [temp] #appending the temperature value at the end
   return temps

temps = temperature()
print(temps)
# Then, use the corresponding function fom matplotlib to fit your needs: 
# plt.plot(temps), plt.scatter(temps), ...
```

However, as I said, you would need a x-axis to make the plot better, perhaps the date. If not, the x-axis will be the indexes of the list 0,1,2,3,... One way to do this is, as we did for the temperature, extract the day from the file and then modify the tick labels of the x-axis with the string. One fast solution could be:

```
# modify the temperature function accordingly to return the following:
days, temperatures = temperature()

plt.bar(x=range(temperatures), height=temperatures)
plt.xtics(ticks=range(len(temperatures)), labels=days)
```